# Starting Node.js Express application

Tags: node.js, express

I created an application with

```
$ express -c stylus express_example
```

I can start my server with

```
$ npm start
```

but

```
$ node app.js
```

&

```
$ nodemon app.js
```

don't seem to work.  I don't get any error messages though, terminal just goes to the next line.  e.g.

```
$ node app.js
$
```

This is my bin/www file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

and my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: do you get any error message?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Figured it out.  Since my server is started in the bin/www file as opposed to the app.js file, from the terminal I went into my bin directory and then called

```
$ node wwww
```

or

```
$ nodemon www
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `npm start` probably calls your `bin/www` file. Which contains the `listen` invocation to start your app.

Many people set up their app this way. eg. `app.js` to define and configure their app, and something like `bin/www` to actual get the server running. This way they can include the `app.js` into other parts, say tests, without actually starting the server when you `require` it.

Answer (score 4):

You have in your package.json file a property where you can point out the entry point of your application. For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```